# Finding a function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{ Z}^+$ that is bijective; injective but not surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given an example, if possible, of a function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ that meets the following requirements. If it is not possible, explain why.

a) bijective

b) injective but not surjective

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] the question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a bijective function is,

$$f(a)= \begin{cases} 
  2a-1  &\text{if $a>0$} \\
  2|a|   &\text{if $a \leq 0$}
\end{cases}$$

If you're considering that $0 \not\in \Bbb Z^+$ then you'll have to take the function, 
$$f(a)= \begin{cases} 
  2a  &\text{if $a>0$} \\
  2|a|+1   &\text{if $a \leq 0$}
\end{cases}$$

An example of a injective function is,
$$f(a)= \begin{cases} 
  2a+5  &\text{if $a>0$} \\
  2|a|+6   &\text{if $a \leq 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is $0\in\Bbb Z^+$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I think so, and usually if we don't want the zero in it we write it ${\Bbb Z^+}^*$.

Comment: I do not think, that 0 is included in $\mathbb{Z}^+$. And does the star not mean, that you exclude $0$ in general, or am I messing something up?

Comment: @Cornman I am no longer sure about that, we usually used to denote it by $\Bbb Z^*=\Bbb Z-\{0\}$. The same applies for the real numbers for example $\Bbb R^*=\Bbb R-\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R^+=\{x \in \Bbb R /: x \ge 0\}$

Comment: At the end, it does not really matter anyways. I think, that the $+$ implies every positiv integer (or real number), which would exclude $0$.

Answer (score 5):

This should be all possible.

A bijective function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}^+$ is given by:

$f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(-1)=3, f(2)=4, f(-2)=5$ 'and so on'.

It should be not that difficult to give an exact definition of $f$ that functions like the principle above.

An injective, but not surjective function, can be constructed like above, where you just start with $f(0)=10$ for example, and then $f(1)=11, f(-1)=12, f(2)=13, f(-2)=14$ and so on.

This function would not be surjective, since $1,2,3,\dotso, 10$ has no preimage.

Note also, that this function is obtained by the first function, where you just add $10$.

If you want an explicit form, you might want to try to find that on your own first.
As I said, it should not be to difficult.
You might want to separate cases for $z\geq 0$ and $z<0$.

Comment: may be a typo.:  $f(0)=1, f(1)=1$ is not bijective

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I edited it.